# Python - Regular expressions get numbers between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, numbers, between, brackets

I need help creating a Regex to get numbers between parenthesis
when my values are between word "PIC" and the "."

I got this records and need to be able to extract values between ()

```
PIC S9(02)V9(05).    I need this result "02 05"
PIC S9(04).          I need this result "04"
PIC S9(03).          I need this result "03"
PIC S9(03)V9(03).    I need this result "03 03" 
PIC S9(02)V9(03).    I need this result "02 03"
PIC S9(04).          I need this result "04"  
PIC S9(13)V9(03).    I need this result "13 03"
```

I have try the below but it doesnt work.

```
s = "PIC S9(02)V9(05)."
m = re.search(r"\([0-9]+([0-9]))\", s)
print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `re.findall()` to find all numbers within the parenthesis:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = [
...     "PIC S9(02)V9(05).",
...     "PIC S9(04).",
...     "PIC S9(03).",
...     "PIC S9(03)V9(03).",
...     "PIC S9(02)V9(03).",
...     "PIC S9(04).",
...     "PIC S9(13)V9(03)."
... ]
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)")
>>> for item in l:
...     print(pattern.findall(item))
... 
['02', '05']
['04']
['03']
['03', '03']
['02', '03']
['04']
['13', '03']
```

where `\(` and `\)` would match the literal parenthesis (needed to be escaped with a backslash because of the special meaning they have). `(\d+)` is a [*capturing group*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) that would match one or more digits.

Comment: Since it seems that the OP is expecting "02 05" instead of a list, you should change `print(pattern.findall(item))` to `print(' '.join(pattern.findall(item)))` *(obviously with a little search he may find it himself)*.

Answer (score 1):

Assumingly, your numbers are somewhat logically connected, you might therefore come up with the following code (including the explanation):

```
import re

string = """
PIC S9(02)V9(05).    I need this result "02 05"
PIC S9(04).          I need this result "04"
PIC S9(03).          I need this result "03"
PIC S9(03)V9(03).    I need this result "03 03" 
PIC S9(02)V9(03).    I need this result "02 03"
PIC S9(04).          I need this result "04"  
PIC S9(13)V9(03).    I need this result "13 03"
"""
rx = re.compile(
    r"""
    \((\d+)\)       # match digits in parentheses
    [^\n(]+         # match anything not a newline or another opening parenthesis
    (?:\((\d+)\))?  # eventually match another group of digits in parentheses
    """, re.VERBOSE)

for match in re.finditer(rx, string):
    if match.group(2):
        m = ' '.join([match.group(1),match.group(2)])
    else:
        m = match.group(1)
    print m
```

See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gW7uN0/1)</kbd> as well as on <kbd>[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/mhicUG)</kbd>.

#### Hint:

If you're having list items, simple go for `\(\d+\)`.