# Regex replace "(x)" with "-x" only next to a number

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I change all parenthesis in a string to a minus sign only when the next character immediately following `(` is a number?

input: `foo (4,301) bar blah (4)% blah (USD)`

output: `foo -4,301 bar blah -4% blah (USD)`

everything that I have found is relating to getting a number and not changing the string...

`num = -int(test.translate(None,"(),"))`

that's not what I want

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: See [Python - Regular expressions get numbers between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632977/python-regular-expressions-get-numbers-between-parenthesis)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. that doesn't work. I'm not trying to extract values.

Comment: So, what does not work? Show the code.

Comment: @Sajuuk. Bro, try doing a "basic google search" on my question and see what you get. Maybe you didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: @Sajuuk I have changed the title to `Regex`, but I'm doing it in python and not in other languages... how is it not a python question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "foo (4,301) bar blah (4)% blah (USD)"
print( re.sub(r"\((\d*,?\d*)\)", r"-\1", s) )
```

**Output:**

```
foo -4,301 bar blah -4% blah (USD)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = 'foo (4,301) bar blah (4)% blah (USD)'
re.sub(r'\((\d[^\)]*)\)', r'-\1', s)
# 'foo -4,301 bar blah -4% blah (USD)'
```

Comment: This will replace `(3 blind mice)` with `-3 blind mice` - are you sure that's the right thing to do?

Comment: OP had said `change all parenthesis in a string to a minus sign only when the next character immediately following ( is a number`. So I think, thats the right thing to do

Comment: You are right: the OP did say that. But I'm almost certain that that's *not* what was really wanted: the specification was incomplete.

Comment: I can just answer based on what was specified. Neither me, nor you can speculate on what the OP actually wants